# How to add wordWrap on spark GridColumn

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

Today, I decided to test spark datagrid instead of mx:Datatagrid.
But a problem appear: I didn't found wordWrap option, do you know how to solve that?

```
<s:DataGrid id="scrollableDG" borderVisible="true"  editable="true"
                     width="100%" height="{bgSuivi.height-90-90}">

 //Setup columns for scrollable datagrid
    var gridColumn:GridColumn = new GridColumn();
    gridColumn.dataField="scRub2";
    gridColumn.headerText = "Rub1";
    gridColumn.width = 80;
    gridColumn.editable = true;
    columnLst.addItem(gridColumn);

    var gridColumn:GridColumn = new GridColumn();
    gridColumn.dataField="scRub3";
    gridColumn.headerText = "Rub1";
    gridColumn.width = 80;
    gridColumn.editable = true;
    columnLst.addItem(gridColumn);

    var gridColumn:GridColumn = new GridColumn();
    gridColumn.dataField="scRub4";
    gridColumn.headerText = "Rub1";
    gridColumn.width = 80;
    gridColumn.editable = true;
    columnLst.addItem(gridColumn);
    scrollableDG.columns = columnLst;
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean "Spark DataGrid **instead** of MX DataGrid" -- rather than putting a Spark DataGrid *inside* an MX DataGrid. Your code example seems to confirm this, but thought I would clarify for everyone. You may want to edit the question to reflect this :)

Answer (score 8):

The original poster didn't select an answer I'm going to combine the previous two into one ***super*** answr! :P

You can enable word wrapping on all columns on the Spark DataGrid with variableRowHeight:

```
<s:DataGrid variableRowHeight="true">
</s:DataGrid>
```

Or you can enable word wrapping on an individual column by using the word wrap property on the default GridColumn item renderer:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="fields.description" headerText="Description" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DefaultGridItemRenderer wordWrap="true"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

Furthermore, in the Grid Column example I'd recommend setting a width if you want to prevent horizontal scroll bars:

```
<s:GridColumn width="{dataGrid.width-column1.width-column3.width}" dataField="fields.description" headerText="Description" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DefaultGridItemRenderer wordWrap="true"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

I'm finding I have to set both variable row height to true and set the column width to get the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: I am looking for somewhat same, thanks for sharing. But my another question is how to set wordWrap property to Column header. In case of long <mx:datagrid its bit easier but so far i am unable to find same thing for <s:datagrid .

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]**

Oops, my original answer was referring to the MX `DataGridColumn` component, not the Spark `GridColumn`. Revised answer...

The default item renderer for the grid is `DataGridItemRenderer` and it has a word wrap property that you need to set to true. Not sure, but you might also have to set the `variableRowHeight` property of the grid to true as well...

To do this in MXML, it would look something like this:

```
<s:DataGrid variableRowHeight="true">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DataGridItemRenderer wordWrap="true" />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I get an error when trying to use this code, 
Could not resolve <s:DataGridItemRenderer> to a component implementation. Note: I see it is pseudo code. I'll see if I find something similar.

Comment: The class is <s:DefaultGridItemRenderer />

Answer (score 0):

Until *flex4.6*, there is no **s**:DataGridItemRenderer, but there is **mx**:DataGridItemRenderer. So, the code would be:

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="foo" labelFunction="fooLabelFunction">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <mx:DataGridItemRenderer wordWrap="true" />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

Comment: I tried to use mx DataGridItemRenderer and it gives this error: 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at spark.components::Group/addElement()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1342]
 at spark.components.gridClasses::GridLayout/createTypicalItemRenderer()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\gridClasses\GridLayout.as:748]
 at spark.components.gridClasses::GridLayout/updateTypicalCellSizes()